# Как можно элегантнее записать этот код. Смущают повторения в цикле

Tags: python, excel, инспекция-кода, openpyxl

Если добавить '\n' и просто умножить на 3, то в эксель все повторения будут записаны в одну строку, и только вот этот повторяющийся код может записать одно и то же число в разные строки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все же правильно записать этот код?

```
import openpyxl


wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook('книга1.xlsx')
ws2a=wb2['лист1']


j = 0
for i in range(70):
    if i==0:
        continue
    elif i==1:
        for g in 'abc':
           ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
           j+=1
           ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
           j+=1
           ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
           j+=1
    elif i==8:
        for h in 'abcd':
            ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='208'+h
            j+=1
            ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='208'+h
            j+= 1
            ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='208'+h
            j+= 1
    elif i<10:
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='20'+str(i)
        j+=1
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='20'+str(i)
        j+=1
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='20'+str(i)
        j+=1
    elif i>=10:
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='2'+ str(i)
        j+=1
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='2' +str(i)
        j+=1
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='2' +str(i)
        j+=1



wb2.save(filename='книга1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе (или выложить) примеры входных и выходных данных?

Comment: @MaxU исправила код, теперь не нужны входные и выходные данные

Comment: без данных не могу предложить вам элегантного решения. Но вам, вероятно, виднее нужны данные или нет ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы этот код:

```
ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
j+=1
ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
j+=1
ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
j+=1
```

Заменил бы функцией, в которой циклом бы выполнял два действия:

```
def function(ws2a, j):
    for i in range(3):
        ws2a.cell(row = 5+j, column = 1).value='201'+g
        j+=1
```

Ну а еще легче, можно воспользоваться pandas

Comment: спасибо! очень помогли =)  а не приведете пример, как с pandas такое можно сделать?

Comment: @user327535, [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)